AddTorque changing 3rd Axis when used specifically on only 2 - Unity 3D
Does anyone know why the following code in AddTorque, specifically applied to x and y axis modifies my Z axis right away?
m_Rigidbody.AddTorque(m_inputThrottle * m_rThrottle.current * Time.fixedDeltaTime, m_input.Pedals * m_rYaw.current * Time.fixedDeltaTime, 0);

AddTorque works fine when applied on only one axis, but modifies all three when I change two (in this case x and y). I'm going crazy here. Anyone know what I can do?
